# Access Ajax POSTed data in a cfm page

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I am trying to use Ajax/JQuery to submit a form, and on the target page (response.cfm) I am returning a Json which will return either a success or a failure message (based on the checkbox) on the form page (form.cfm). But I can't seem to access the data sent by the ajax request.

form.cfm

```
<form id="frm_test">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First name" required /><br>
  <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Surname" required /><br>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required /><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="error" id="error" />Return error (check to see the error message. leave empty to see a success message)<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Save changes" id="submitdata" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

  $("#frm_test").submit(function (eventData) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#message").empty();
    var postData = {
      first_name: $('#firstname').val(),
      family_name: $('#surname').val(),
      email: $('#email').val(),
      error: $('#error').is(':checked')
    };

    $.ajax({
      url: "response.cfm",
      method: "POST",
      data: postData
    }).done(
      function(response) {
        if (response["SUCCESSMESSAGE"] !== null) {
          $("#message").append(response["SUCCESSMESSAGE"]);
        } else if (response["EXCEPTIONMESSAGE"] !== null) {
          $("#message").append(response["EXCEPTIONMESSAGE"]);
        }
      });

    $("#frm_test").trigger("reset");
  });

</script>


<div id="message"></div>
```

response.cfm

```
<cfprocessingdirective suppresswhitespace="Yes">

  <cfset response = {
    SuccessMessage: 'checkbox value' ? JavaCast("null", "") : "Success",
    ExceptionMessage: 'checkbox value' ? "An error occurred" : JavaCast("null", "")
  }>
  
  <cfheader name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
    
  <cfoutput> #serializeJSON(response)# </cfoutput>  
  
</cfprocessingdirective>
```

Comment: are there any errors in the response page? can you check the coldfusion logs?

Comment: You should do a console.log of the response of the ajax call to see what being returned, my guess is you're using `SUCCESSMESSAGE` instead of `SuccessMessage`, notice the difference in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for the posted value for `error` which will be available in the `form` scope.

```
  <cfset response = {
    SuccessMessage: form.error ? JavaCast("null", "") : "Success",
    ExceptionMessage: form.error ? "An error occurred" : JavaCast("null", "")
  }>
```

Comment: Why didn't this work the first time I tried it? Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Dan's solution

```
<cfsilent>

... 

<cfset response = [
   "SuccessMessage" : form.error ? JavaCast("null", "") : "Success",
   "ExceptionMessage" : form.error ? "An error occurred" : JavaCast("null", "")
 ]>

 ...

 <cfsilent>  

 <cfoutput> #serializeJSON(response)# </cfoutput>
```

So what are the changes?

1. silent is the most effective in keeping stray spaces
2. Using an ordered struct makes it easier to debug because the results stay in the same order
3. Using quoted keys keeps them in the same case which also makes it easier to debug.